# Issue on EF Core query: Method not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 web projetcts (1 MVC and 1 API), using the same Library (.Net Core 1.1) that calls some EF Core querys... everytime I try to get data from the MVC (.Net Core 1.1) it works fine, but when I try to access it from API (.Net Core 2.0) I get the following error message:

Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.ReferenceCollectionBuilder`2<!0,!1> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.ReferenceCollectionBuilder`2.OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior)'.

I don't think the .Net Core version would affect this since the query is called from same library

Does anyone knows how to help me ?

Comment: I tried it with simple querys like:

_context.Materials.Count()

Comment: .NET Core version very much *would* affect this, as the EF Core version is somewhat tied to that. You'd need to ensure that the EF reference is being supplied in both cases by the least common denominator version (i.e. EF 1.1, since you've got a .NET Core 1.1 project in play. In particular, if your .NET Core 2.0 project references EF Core 2.0, then that reference will be employed when trying to access the class library as well, causing potential version conflicts.

Comment: Really, you should keep all your .NET Core versions the same. If you're not ready to upgrade everything to .NET Core 2.0, then stick with .NET Core 1.1 for new projects. Otherwise, go ahead and update everything that is interconnected in any way to all utilize the latest .NET Core. Trying to mix and match while sharing dependencies is going to kill you.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt, it wasn't my fault though, I'll try to solve this conflict, and if I can't, will change everything to .NET Core 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with this problem is that you are trying to call EF core 1.1 from Dotnet core 2.2.
I had same issue, I have resolved by updating everything to same version of dotnet core.
In my case, data project was made on ef core 1.1 and web project was 2.0, and I updated the data project and web project to same version.
In case, if you are not allowed to update to latest stable version (i.e. EF Core 2.2 and .NET Core 2.2), and then at least stick to make a call to EF Core project from same version.